# Write specifics rows with specific column values in python csv

Tags: python, csv, row

I have a csv file and I need to write lines with a common value in one of the columns in another csv file, how can I do this?

Comment: What are you using to read/write the csv's ?

Comment: The csv python module

Comment: Sorry I meant once read where do you store ? My point is using numpy or pandas would make this easier.

Comment: I fail to see why you cannot just find the value, assign it to a variable and use this variable when saving your new CSV

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand your problem, you want to read csv file, then based on a condition on any column's value you want to filter it and finally write into a csv file.
If I am correct then you can do the following :

```
#Import pandas

import pandas as pd

#Read your csv file as pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv("your_csv_file_name")

#Apply filter condition
df = df[df['Column_name_for_fitering'] == "Value_for_filtering"]

# Save as new csv file
df.to_csv('your_output_file_name')
```